# Python os.system open again and again program

Tags: python, os.system

I want to open a program once and then continuously print "explorer opened":

```
import os 
while True:
    os.system("start explorer.exe")
    print("explorer opened")
```

Again and again `open explorer.exe`, I don't want to `While' with a break statement.

Comment: I think you're going to need to clarify what you're asking. And please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my best guess at what you wanted from your question

```
import os 
already_ran = False
os.system("start explorer.exe")
while True:
    #If not already ran run the explorer 
    if already_ran == False:
       os.system("start explorer.exe")
       already_ran = True #now that is is ran do not run it again

    print("explorer opened")
```

The code above will run `explorer.exe` once and then will print `explorer opened` indefinitely

Comment: but in while :)

Comment: @Muhametaga07 I edited it to be in while

Comment: I have a question I want all harddisk scan(C:\ D:\ E:\) Exp:                             `pass = open("C:\password.txt","r")`                                                                 `pass.readline()`

Comment: @Muhametaga07 if you have another question please ask if as a new question please do not ask it in the comments [Please look at this article on how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)